# Cannot make development database with rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

***Update***: Running

```
RAILS_ENV=development rake db:create
```

... works. But the rake commands without the `RAILS_ENV` prefix don't. What gives?

---

For some reason, I am no longer able to interact with my development database at all anymore.

I've tried `rake db:create`, and it makes my test database fine, but the dev one is not created at all.

I'm using the [postgresapp.com](http://postgresapp.com), and up until just recently, it was working flawlessly. No changes to my `config/database.yml` file have been made recently, nor to any of my app config files.

I can connect to my test database fine with `psql -h localhost redtail_test`, and it uses the same connection credentials as my dev box, so I'm reasonably sure it's not a connection issue with PG--unless it's a weird one.

```
redtail git:master ❯ rake db:create
redtail_test already exists
redtail git:master ❯ psql -h localhost redtail  
psql: FATAL:  database "redtail" does not exist
```

Has anyone ran into this issue?

---

```
common: &common
  encoding: utf8

postgres: &postgres
  adapter: postgresql
  user: postgres
  password:
  min_messages: WARNING

development: &development
  <<: *common
  <<: *postgres
  host: localhost
  database: redtail

memory: &memory
  <<: *common
  adapter: sqlite3
  host: localhost
  database: ":memory:"

test: &test
  <<: *common
  <<: *postgres
  host: localhost
  database: redtail_test

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: redtail

cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

Comment: If you are using Rails 3.2.7, there was a regression that caused rake and the development env to have issues.  It has been fixed in 3.2.8 which is currently in its 2nd release candidate and should be out soon. http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Btw, having the same issue with 3.2.8 stable...